# Efficient rsync

Tags: rsync, timestamps, size

Now 5 years after [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17286290) was orignially asked, is there a way for `rsync` to do the following?

> - same time and same size ► skip file (no transfer, no checksum)
> - different sizes ► transfer file (no checksum)
> - different times and same size ► perform checksum ► transfer only if checksums differ

In my case, I have a network share that is accessible through multiples OS (one that uses UTC and another that uses RTC - I do not have admin/root access on either, so I cannot change it). Modifying the file in one OS changes the time so that it is a few hours ahead/behind the "real" time, depending on which OS I browse the files. If I modify a file, the timestamp will be "incorrect".

Comment: `rync`'s option `-u, --update` This forces rsync to skip any files which exist on the destination and have  a  modified time that is newer than the source file.  (If an existing destination file has a modification time equal to the source file’s, it will be updated if the sizes are different.) -- This is not exactly what you want, but should help when the time differs 'one way'. So if you 'dry run' `rsync` with swapped source and target you should be able to catch time differences both ways.

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand, the linked question is very confusing.  The answer by 9mjb is correct.

On the other hand, if you are using rsync on a local mount of a network filesystem, there is no way it can checksum the remote file without downloading the whole file anyway!  So you are going to be stuck with slowness here.  Assuming you have less network bandwidth available than the disk speed.

Except I don't understand what problem you are trying to explain about times, either.  If you use `-a`, it should transfer the exact times from the source system.  If you don't use `-a`, it won't transfer the original times from the source filesystem, therefore the times will not match exactly for subsequent transfers anyway.  It sounds like you don't want `-u` behaviour, but then you can just not use `-u` :-).

---

`rsync` is efficient by default.   (At the cost of "if time and size both match, the chance that the files are different is insignificant, I'm willing to take the risk not to transfer").

> [[rsync](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html)] is famous  for  its
>          delta-transfer  algorithm,  which  reduces the amount of data sent over
>          the network by sending only the differences between  the  source  files
>          and  the  existing  files in the destination. Rsync is widely used for
>          backups and mirroring and as an improved copy command for everyday use.
>
> Rsync finds files that need to be transferred  using  a  "quick  check"
>          algorithm  (by  default) that looks for files that have changed in size
>          or  in  last-modified  time.

The important thing to understand is that the rsync delta-transfer algorithm, and the "quick check", are separate.

It sounds like you don't want the behaviour of `--checksum`.  `--checksum` disables the "quick check" part.  In that case, *don't use `--checksum`*.

> -c, --checksum
>
> This changes the way rsync checks if the files have been changed
>                 and are in need of a transfer.  Without this option, rsync  uses
>                 a "quick check" that (by default) checks if each file’s size and
>                 time of last modification match between the sender and receiver.
>                 This  option changes this to compare a 128-bit checksum for each
>                 file that has a matching size.  Generating the  checksums  means
>                 that  both  sides  will expend a lot of disk I/O reading all the
>                 data in the files in the transfer (and  this  is  prior  to  any
>                 reading  that  will  be done to transfer changed files), so this
>                 can slow things down significantly.
>
> The sending side generates its checksums while it is  doing  the
>                 file-system  scan  that  builds the list of the available files.
>                 The receiver generates its checksums when  it  is  scanning  for
>                 changed files, and will checksum any file that has the same size
>                 as the corresponding sender’s file:  files with either a changed
>                 size or a changed checksum are selected for transfer.
>
> Note  that  rsync always verifies that each transferred file was
>                 correctly reconstructed on the  receiving  side  by  checking  a
>                 whole-file  checksum  that  is  generated  as the file is trans‐
>                 ferred, but that automatic after-the-transfer  verification  has
>                 nothing  to do with this option’s before-the-transfer "Does this
>                 file need to be updated?" check.

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly, this does not look possible with a built-in rsync option!

This may work:

```
rsync -an --info=name src dest \
    | rsync -an --info=name --checksum --files-from - src dest
```

Explanation:

The first rsync command uses the default rsync mode of checking time and size. It outputs any directory or filename with a different time or size. Because of the -n flag, no files are transferred.

The second rsync command takes the list of files with a changed time or size from the first rsync and then runs rsync again on just those files with the --checksum argument.

The second command has -n for dry run mode, so only the file names will be printed. Remove -n from the second command to actually transfer the files.